# What is the second parameter in this Prolog predicate doing? Why is it empty?

Tags: prolog, dcg

In [this page](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse29) detailing DCGs in Prolog, it offers the following example grammar:

```
s  -->  np,vp. 

np  -->  det,n. 

vp  -->  v,np. 
vp  -->  v. 

det  -->  [the]. 
det  -->  [a]. 

n  -->  [woman]. 
n  -->  [man]. 

v  -->  [shoots].
```

Which can be used as such:

```
s([a,woman,shoots,a,man],[]).
```

What is the second parameter doing? Why is it `[]` or empty? I would think you would just call `s([a,woman,shoots,a,man]).` but it will not work.

Could someone explain what passing an empty list is accomplishing here and what it does?

Comment: As it says in the link you gave, *That is, just as in the difference list recogniser, we ask whether we can get an s by consuming the symbols in [a,woman,shoots,a,man] , **leaving nothing behind**.* In other words, the DCG expects the second argument is "what's left" after processing the input. Since in this case, you want nothing left, the argument is `[]`. You can also use, `phrase(s, [a,woman,shoots,a,man])`, which is the more common way to call a DCG. And to generate all recognized sentences, `phrase(s, L).`.

Comment: I read that, but I don't understand why passing a second argument is designated as what it expects to leave behind. Where is that logic indicated in the first code block?

Comment: That logic is "under the hood" in a DCG. Here's an exercise: run your Prolog interpreter, load the DCG example program (from a file, for example), then do `listing.` This will show you what the actual predicates are and you'll see the second argument. If you use `phrase`, and just the DCG notation, this argument is implicit. The tutorial is a little misleading for not introducing the `phrase` predicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend to *always* use the `phrase/2` interface to access DCGs.

The reason is that you should not rely on any particular expansion method for DCG clauses. Your system may expand DCGs the way as outlined on this page, but relying on this property prevents many optimizations that would otherwise have been possible.

In your case, you should read up on the meaning  `phrase/2`, and use it like this:

```
?- phrase(NT, Ls).
```

with the meaning that the DCG nonterminal `NT` describes the list `Ls`.

Thus, you notice that you do not even see any empty list here! Therefore, using `phrase/2` makes using DCGs also easier for beginners than thinking in terms of additional arguments.

If you really need to access the remainder of the list, which is sometimes useful, you can always use `phrase/3`. In fact, `phrase(NT, Ls)` is shorthand for `phrase(NT, Ls, [])`, but you do not need to worry about this so soon. It will come naturally to you when you have more experience with Prolog.

Comment: s(X) for promoting `phrase/2..3`, which enables the use of many convenient short forms in `NT`, like this: `?- phrase((("a"|"b"),"123",("x"|"y")),Xs).`